# NodeJS read file with Japanese characters

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I am trying to read file (on Windows 8) with Japanese in it:

```
fs.readFile(this.directory + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => { 

      //data is BO1_�G���g�����X   
});
```

I expect *data* to be something like this: B01_ブラGウザgでX.

What is the right way to read file with Japanese?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is your console actually capable of displaying these characters?

Comment: @RadLexus I have also tried to write data to file and it's the same as the output in the question..

Comment: If your console can print those characters, your file is probably not encoded in `utf-8`. Try opening the file in an editor that lets you specify the encoding and see which encoding shows the characters correctly.

Comment: How did you check? By writing the data back to your console? Which would lead us again to "is your console actually capable of displaying these characters" ... Open the file with a *good* text editor (one of which you are absolutely positive it can display Japanese) and check with that.

Comment: @洋葱头 Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you know the encoding of your input file. `Utf-8` is probably wrong. A good way of doing this is opening the file in an editor that supports different encodings. Then check which encoding displays the characters correctly. I like using [Edit Pad Lite](http://www.editpadlite.com/) for these purposes.

Comment: what if it is a server that processes files from user? how on earth can the server know what encoding the users save their files with? Especially if the server has global users? Any suggestions on that?